# Powershell compare arrays and get unique values

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am currently trying to write a powershell script that can be run weekly on two CSV files, to check they both contain the same information. I want the script to output anything that appears in one file but not the other to a new file.

The script I have written so far compares the two but only adds <= and => to the values.
It also doesn't work all the time, because I manually checked the file and found results that existed in both.

Code below:

```
    $NotPresents = compare-object -ReferenceObject $whatsup -DifferenceObject $vmservers -Property device 

foreach ($NotPresent in $NotPresents)
{

Write-Host $NotPresent.device 
}


$NotPresents | Out-File Filepath.txt
$NotPresents.count
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: You have done nothing wrong, compare-object shows you where the entry is located and where not by showing `=>`... You can just filter for the arrows to know which entry is where. Also, if you want to see entries that are in both, you have to use `-includeEqual`.

Comment: Thats the point though, I don't want to see entries that are in both, yet they are appearing. Currently the output is exactly the same as the input files

Comment: Please edit your question and supply some example input files and the output, so we can take a better look at the problem.

Comment: Also you don't need `foreach` part, you can do it with just `$NotPresents | Select-Object device`

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid having to iterate over one of the arrays more than once*, you may want to throw them each into a `hashtable`:

```
$whatsupTable = @{}
foreach($entry in $whatsup){
  $whatsupTable[$entry.device] = $true
}

$vmserversTable = @{}
foreach($entry in $vmservers){
  $vmserversTable[$entry.device] = $true
}
```

Now you can easily find the disjunction with a single loop and a lookup against the other table:

```
$NotInWhatsUp   = $vmservers |Where { -not $whatsupTable[$_]   }
$NotInVMServers = $whatsup   |Where { -not $vmserversTable[$_] }
```

---

<sup>**) ok, technically we're looping through each twice, but still much better than nested looping*</sup>